# Как отличить ВСЁ ТАКЖЕ от ВСЁ ТАК ЖЕ?

Tags: союзы, также

В Нацкорпусе  можно встретить **оба варианта,** причем складывается впечатление, что пользователям сложно различить эти формы.

Я могу предположить, что союзное соединение ***всё также*** имеет значение **по-прежнему** и используется **для сопоставления тождественных ситуаций.**

В этом случае его **надо отличать** от местоименного выражения  ***всё так же, как***, отнесенного к признаку (**сравнение степени признака**).

И этим ***всё также*** отличается от  присоединительного союза ***также*** со значением **кроме того, вдобавок**.

Вот примеры:

1) **Союз ТАКЖЕ**: сопоставления тождественных ситуаций

Первый фильм интересный, второй **также**. Первый фильм интересный, **также как и**  второй. Первый фильм был интересный, **всё также** (= по-прежнему) интересен и второй фильм.

2) **Местоимение ТАК и частица ЖЕ**: одинаковая степень признака

Первый фильм **так же** интересен, как второй. Первый фильм **всё так же** интересен, как второй.

3) **Союз ТАКЖЕ**: присоединительный (кроме того, вдобавок)

Игра актеров мне понравилась, **также** вызывает интерес работа режиссера.

Comment: Хоть какие-то ссылки на какие-то правила можете добавить?

Comment: Нету ссылок на правила, это же не ответ, а вопрос. И потом, какие правила, здесь только грамматика, разные функции местоимения и союза, которые надо вычислить. Пример: Он всё также бегает по утрам?  Можно отнести местоимение "так" к глаголу "бегает", может оно обозначать образ действия? Вряд ли. Я, конечно, понимаю, о каких ссылках Вы говорите. Кто-то должен озаботиться этим вопросом и решить эту задачу за нас. Таких ссылок у меня нет

Comment: Дело в том, что все известные мне правила противоречат тому, что Вы пишете о союзе ТАКЖЕ:  "для сопоставления тождественных ситуаций", "всё также = по-прежнему". Но не только Вы пишете, в Нацкорпусе тоже есть такое. Получается, обнаружился такой разрыв между теорией и практикой?

Comment: Вот и напишите об этом в ответе, расскажите о своем понимании проблемы. Я задавала ухе вопрос о союзах ТОЖЕ и ТАКЖЕ, на него никто не ответил. Неинтересно, не нужно? Я не знаю. И на этот вопрос никто не отвечает.

Comment: Написал. Надеюсь, кто-то из знатоков откликнется.

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос четко не сформулирован, поэтому и ответ мой не будет конкретным.
Часть из того, что написано в вопросе о союзе ТАКЖЕ (он служит "для сопоставления тождественных ситуаций", "всё также" означает "по-прежнему") противоречит известным мне правилам и пособиям, которые объясняют, как отличить ТАКЖЕ от ТАК ЖЕ. Но есть факты, от которых не уйдешь, в Нацкорпусе встречается употребление ТАКЖЕ в смысле *по-прежнему*. Получается, обнаружился сильный разрыв между теорией и практикой.

Comment: Как же не чётко сформулирован вопрос, ведь написано: как отличить "всё также" от "всё так же"? По текстам в Нацкорпусе я вижу, что кто-то пишет по формальным правилам "всё так же",  полагая, что это сравнение (= всё так же, как), а кто-то пишет так, как считает правильным, потому что видит, что это союз, а не местоимение. Вот и интересно подумать: только ли присоединительное значение у союза ТАКЖЕ? Может быть, можно назвать и другое значение?

Comment: @Jasmin Любопытен ответ Грамоты на "Вопрос № 255019".

Comment: Вопрос № 255019. Вы все также молоды, вы все также вместе. Слово ТАКЖЕ пишется в данном случае слитно? Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Слитное написание возможно, если здесь также синонимично слову "тоже". Ну да, здесь не степень признака, а тождественность ситуаций: они молоды,  вы также молоды. Но замена союзов не всегда возможна.

Comment: @Jasmin, согласен с Грамотой. К тому же рассматривать слитное написание в значении по- прежнему, неправильно. Вы же сами прекрасно знаете, что в этом значении - это наречие.

Comment: В словаре у Кузнецова слов ТОЖЕ названо наречием, а не союзом, слова могут менять свои функции. Вот предложение: Он все также был в мокрой шинели и при амуниции. [П. Н. Краснов.  (1922)]  Какой Вы подберете синоним?

Comment: @Jasmin, Национальный корпус все же не является источником проверки орфографии. Ошибки не исключены. Да и посмотрите на год издания.